# Join and perform aggregation on 2 csv files in python without using panda or sqlite library

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, join, aggregation

For the task, assume that we have a database with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
transaction_id UUID,
date DATE,
user_id UUID,
is_blocked BOOL,
transaction_amount INTEGER,
transaction_category_id INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id UUID,
is_active BOOLEAN
);
```

Example data for these tables is stored in the corresponding CSV files - transactions.csv and
users.csv, which can be generated from the generate_data.py script.
I want to compute the result of the following query:

```
SELECT
t.transaction_category_id,
SUM(t.transaction_amount) AS sum_amount,
COUNT(DISTINCT t.user_id) AS num_users
FROM transactions t
JOIN users u USING (user_id)
WHERE t.is_blocked = False
AND u.is_active = 1
GROUP BY t.transaction_category_id
ORDER BY sum_amount DESC;
```

I have to write a Python program using only the Python Standard Library1,2
(preferably not using external libraries at all), which reads data from CSV files
transactions.csv and users.csv, and computes the equivalent result of the SQL query in
an efficient way that would be scalable for large data sets as well. The result should be printed to stdout.

I am new to python so finding it difficult to implement the above code.

I have written the below code that helps to merge the two csv file, but dont know how I can use where or group by or order by .

```
import csv

transactions_file = open('M:\\Codebase\\PySpark\\test\\new\\transactions.csv', 'r')
users_file = open('M:\\Codebase\\PySpark\\test\\new\\users.csv', 'r')

transactions_reader1 = list(csv.reader(transactions_file))
users_reader1 = list(csv.reader(users_file))

transactions_reader = list(filter(None, transactions_reader1))
users_reader = list(filter(None, users_reader1))

data = []

for i in range(len(transactions_reader)):
    for j in range(len(users_reader)):
        output_line = []

    # Creating Headers
        if i == 0 and j == 0:
            output_line = ['transaction_id', 'date', 'user_id', 'is_blocked', 'transaction_amount', 'transaction_category_id', 'is_active']

    # Creating data
        else:

            users_line = users_reader[j]
            transactions_line = transactions_reader[i]

            if users_line[0] == transactions_line[2]:
                if str(transactions_line[3]) == 'False' and str(users_line[1]) == 'True':
                    output_line = [transactions_line[2],
                                   float(transactions_line[4]),
                                   int(transactions_line[5])]

        data.append(output_line)


data = list(filter(None, data))
output = []
last = None
data.pop(0)
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[2])

for (user_id, transaction_amount, transaction_category_id) in data:
    if int(transaction_category_id) != last:
        output.append([int(transaction_category_id), 0, 0])
        last = int(transaction_category_id)
        ids = set()
    if user_id not in ids :
        output[-1][1] += 1
        ids.add(user_id)
    output[-1][2] += float(transaction_amount)

output = sorted(output, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)

output.insert(0, "['transaction_category_id', 'num_users', 'sum_amount']")
print(*output, sep = "\n")
```

I have written the above code and able to get the require result

Comment: [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) and [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) are part of the [Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html), so go ahead and use them.

Comment: hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver
they have already mentioned that I can't use sqlite